# eevee animation renders only first frame

Tags: rendering, animation, eevee-render-engine

I am a beginner and made a pretty simple animation in blender, but when I try to render it with eevee(i go to render and then render animation) it only renders the first frame.
I tried to render it as individual frames as jpeg s and directly as a mp4 but both dont work.
Does anyone know what to do?[image]

Comment: What do you click / what shortcut do you use for rendering ? Render Animation is CTRL + F12

Comment: I dont use shortcut for that. I go to render and press render animation

Comment: it seems a quite complex scene, does this happen also on a fresh new file?

Comment: It can be anything. Try to open _Python Console_ the same way you open _3D Viewport, Shader Editor_, etc. Type in or copy/paste from here: `bpy.ops.render.render('INVOKE_DEFAULT', animation=True)` and hit _Enter_. This is the direct _Python_ call of _Render Animation_ operator.

Comment: The render with Python script doesnt work eighter. I will try to recreate the project and make it cleaner. mabey it will work.

Comment: It works fine if I try to animate a moving cube.